# Feature for a signal classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-extraction

Consider that i  have `N` signals of electricity energy consumption (from `N` different consumers) that ha 24 measurements over a single day each (1 measure per hour). These original signals are called `x0` and labeled as class `0`. So, a matrix with `N` rows and `25` columns (24 measurments + 1 class label)

Using these `x0` signals, i generated more `N` synthetic signals multiplying each `x0` signal for a random value `a = random(0.1, 0.9)`. I called these new generated signals `x1` and labeled them as class `1`. Now my matrix has `2N` rows and `25` columns.

The question:

Using a machine learning approach, wich feature could i use to classify if a signal is from class `0` or class `1`? I am asking this because there is a problem where a consumer from the original data `x0` with low energy consumption profile could be missclassified as a sample from `x1`.

So far i have tried the average and variance value of a signal as additional input to my classifier, wich improved the classification accuracy a bit, but it is still far from acceptable.

Any ideas what else i could try? Any temporal, statistical or frequency domain feature will do.